# Keymando: Removing modifier keys when Sending keystrokes

Tags: keymando

When sending keystrokes using Keymando, is it possible to remove the currently held down modifiers?

An example:

```
map "<Cmd-d>" do
    send("a")
end
```

This sends `Cmd+a` rather than `a` which is what I want. (This is a made up example, but illustrates the point.)

AutoHotkey (which is a key remapping and automation tool for Windows) releases any held-down modifier keys when sending keystrokes (and if modifier keys are required not to be released, one can specify a parameter for that as well).

How can I do the same in Keymando? 
Even if there is no "smart" way to release held down modifiers, can I manually specify the modifiers I want released (Again, AutoHotkey allows one to send keystrokes like `{Ctrl Up}`. Is there something similar in Keymando)

Finally, are there any other, more powerful alternatives to Keymando for the Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the latest 1.4 version.

http://keymando.com/download.html

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, I have since started using KeyRemap4MacBook, which I find better documented, robust, has better performance and allows certain key remappings that Keymando doesn't support. Not to mention it's free. 
The only thing it lacks is support for a scripting language, but if one's needs are limited to key-remapping, it is clearly a superior alternative.
However, if Keymando overcame issues I mention, I'm sure I'd be willing to try it again.